# Create a service with a custom command to check status with systemd

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a script that sets some iptables rules (`/bin/myrules`).

I start it with systemd using this unit file `myrules.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Rules

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/myrules start
ExecStop=/sbin/myrules stop
RemainAfterExit=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would like to let systemd know that, after the script is executed and exited, the service is "alive" (if iptables rules are correctly set).

My script is already able to check the status of my iptables rules. Running :

```
/bin/myrules status
```

will return a 0 exit code if everything is OK. If there is something wrong, it will return 1.

*Is it possible to make the `systemctl status myrule` command call my specific script to check if status is OK and return a message accordingly ?*

**Edit**: I need `systemctl status myrules` to display something like

```
Active: active (whatever)
```

[**Edit-2**] But if anything modifies any of the `iptables` rules, **it should re-check** if all rules are active and then display

```
Active: inactive (whatever)
```

This is possible only if it runs `myrules status` to check service status.

PS: I don't need more information about iptables, I use the -C option to check

Answer (score 2):

With the oneshot type systemd will run the process and once it returns consider the process completed and go back to inactive or if `RemainAfterExit=yes` keep the service active even after the process has exited.

If your `ExecStart` script succeeds in changing the iptables configurations it should `exit 0` and if it fails it should `exit 1`. With the use of the `RemainAfterExit=yes` and the process `exit 0` with success it will consider the service active.

You could also use `ExecStartPost=` to run the status command which will cause the service to fail if the status command fails. However this also means the commands in `ExecStart` must `exit 0`.

Comment: The `ExecStartPost=` executes once the verification command. But if something happens after that, `systemctl status` is not updated

Comment: @lauhub That status comes from the main process indicated by ExecStart. Thats why I mentioned that method first. Your main process should be exiting with proper status codes.

Comment: It is exiting with proper status code, but it is not my question: I wonder if there is a solution integrated into systemd that can check for current status (and not startup status) like for other services which can be restarted if they are dead